# Replace spaces with dash and remove prefix from string

Tags: python, string, replace, prefix

I'm using this to remove spaces and special characters and convert characters to lowercase:

```
''.join(e for e in artistName if e.isalnum()).lower()
```

I want to:

- replace spaces with `-`
- if the string starts with the word `the`, then it

So that, for instance, `The beatles music!` would become `beatles-music`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
artistName = artistName.replace(' ', '-').lower()
if artistName.startswith('the-'):
    artistName = artistName[4:]
artistName = ''.join(e for e in artistName if e.isalnum() or e == '-')
```

Comment: `...startswith('the-')` would be better; an artist may be named **theodore** ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to make a machine readable slug. Using a library for this function will save you lots of headache. [python-slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify) does what you are asking for and a bunch of other things you might not have even thought of.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Python 3.9`, you can also use [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=removeprefix#str.removeprefix):

```
'The beatles music'.replace(' ', '-').lower().removeprefix('the-')
# 'beatles-music'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be best done with a bunch of regex-es so you can easily add to it over time.

Not sure of the python syntax but if it was perl you'd do something like:

```
s/^The //g;  #remove leading "The "
s/\s/-/g;    #replace whitespaces with dashes
```

It looks like python has a nice little howto for regexes: http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: An answer should have some code that works, especially with regexes b/c, since it varies so much from language to language.  Not the regexes so much as the commands.